# Difference between pre-image and inverse, counterexample.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inverse-function

I was asked to prove if $X = Y$, then $f^{-1}(X) \neq f^{-1}(Y)$ . I was only able to prove this to be true for the inverse but the comment I got back said I was confusing inverse with pre-image, and that the equality doesn't hold if $f^{-1}$ denotes the pre-image rather than the inverse.

Now, I thought it would be the same because they are represented in the same notation, but I lost points on the actual question. Could someone explain the case for pre-image? What couterexample would work?

My Proof For The Inverse:
Let $x\in f^{-1}(X)$ 
Then $f(x)\in X$
Since $X = Y$, $f(x)\in Y$, so
$x$ $\in$ $f^{-1}(Y)$, so $f^{-1}(X)$ $\subset$ $f^{-1}(Y)$.

Similarly, go opposite way to prove $f^{-1}(Y)$ $\subset$ $f^{-1}(X)$ and conclude they are equal because both sides are subset of each other.

Comment: Can you please add to your post the proof that you refer to when you say that you proved this for the inverse case?  That not only shows the kind of effort we want to see on this site, but it may also help explain my question what you even mean by claiming that there are somehow two different interpretations or cases to this theorem: I can only see one

Comment: Just made those changes.

Comment: Use `\in` to render $\in$!

Comment: Your proof seems fine. Of course, if X=Y, then of course whatever you do to X or say about X will be the same for Y! That is: if X=Y then foo(X) = foo(Y) for whatever foo simply by identity substitution. Anyway, I don’t see why you lost points and I still do not understand what this ‘it’s only true for the inverse but not the pre-image’ is supposed to mean …. Could you post maybe what exactly you wrote and wgat exactly the feedback was?